# Matrix A and B (both mxn) have the same four spaces, proof this: (Is my reasoning ok?)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

Suppose the m by n matrices A and B have the same four subspaces. If they are
both in row reduced echelon form, prove that F = G:

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
I & F \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}
I & G \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

My reasoning:
Because we know they have the same Nullspace, then

\begin{array}{l}
\text{if $Ax=0$ and $Bx=0$ then }
\text{$Ax-Bx=0$}
\text{ then $(A-B)x=0$ because x $\ne$ 0}
\end{array}
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & F-G \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}=0
$$
So, $F-G=0$ then $F=G$
¿What do you think? ¿Is this ok? ¿How would you do this?
Thank you.

Comment: Your reasoning is not correct. The fact that $Ax = 0$ and $Bx = 0$ holds for all $x$ in their common nullspace is not enough to conclude that $(A - B) = 0$.

Comment: Why is not enough? Because also includes the 0 vector? Would you mind to give me an example?

Comment: For example, if we have
$$
A = \pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & 0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{2 & 0\\0 &0},
$$
then the matrices have the same four spaces and their common nullspace is spanned by $(0,1)$. It is true that whenever $x$ is in their common nullspace, $(A - B)x = 0$. However, it is not true that $A - B = 0$.

Comment: I see! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x,y$ be column vectors of the appropriate size (the number of entries in $x$ is the size of $I$, the number of entries in $y$ is the number of columns in $F$). From the fact that the two matrices share the same nullspace, we have
$$
\pmatrix{I & F\\0 & 0} \pmatrix{x\\y} = 0 \iff\pmatrix{I & G\\0 & 0}\pmatrix{x\\y} = 0\\
x + Fy = 0 \iff x + Gy = 0\\
Fy = -x\iff Gy = -x.
$$
With that, we see that $Fy = Gy$ must hold for all possible vectors $y$. From that, we conclude that $F = G$, as desired.

Comment: Something like this I was expecting. Thank you!